# Step in computation of the expected cover time for the simple random walk on a discrete circle

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

I'm having a little trouble understanding part of an example in Lawler's Intro to Stochastic Processes ("Simple Random Walk on a Circle" example on page 32). The problem is the following:

> Suppose $\{X_n, n \geq 0 \}$ is a simple random walk on a cycle (or "clique", as in graph theory) of length $N$. Compute the expected number of steps the process takes to hit every vertex.

I'll go through the main parts of his solution and point out which part is causing my confusion.

---

Let $T_k$ be the time at which the random walk has hit $k$ distinct vertices (so, $T_1 = 0$ and $T_2 = 1$ a.s.). We compute the quantity
$$
r(k):= \mathbb{E} (T_k - T_{k-1}), \hspace{5mm} 3 \leq k \leq N
$$
Observe that at time $T_{k-1}$, the walk has reached the $(k-1)^{\text{th}}$ distinct vertext, and will either hit a new vertex or return to its other neighbor (a vertex that has already been visited). Now, applying the result of the gambler's ruin problem,

> $$ r(k) = 1+\frac{1}{2} \Big( (k-3) +r(k) \Big)$$

Hence, $r(k) = k-1$, and
$$
\mathbb{E}(T_N) = 1+ \sum_{n = 3}^{N} r(k) = \frac{N(N-1)}{2}
$$

---

I understand that the $(k-3)$ in the above blockquote comes from a direct application of the gambler's ruin problem (expected time until absorption for a simple random walk with absorbing boundaries), but I'm having a hard time convincing myself why this formula for $r(k)$ is valid. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I think the $k-3$ should be $r(k-1)$ and $r(k)$ should be $r(k+1)$. The intuition is that from $r(k)$ you have to move 1 step to go somewhere. You can either go up or go down by one step (Assuming 1-D random walk with unit steps with equal probability). So with probability $1 \over 2$, you reach  $r(k-1)$ and with probability $1 \over 2$, you reach  $r(k+1)$. This completely describes the state of $r(k)$ which leads to the equation.

Comment: @karmanaut: I think you misinterpreted which situation/state $r(k)$ relates to. It is only relevant when $(k-1)$ vertices have been visitid and the random walk is at one of the end points of those $(k-1)$ vertices. Like the state when $T_{k-1}$ has just been reached.

Comment: Building on what @String said: $r(k)$ is the average time between hitting the $(k-1)$th distinct vertex and the $k$th distinct vertex. So, I don't think "reaching $r(k-1)$" makes sense

Comment: @eeeeeeeeee: I am in on that, but it still models the situation where you start from one end of $(k-1)$ visited vertices and ask for the expected remaining time before $k$ vertices have been visited. So it is related to the mean of all such situations, if that makes sense.

Comment: @String - See below for a nice explanation and (an easier alternative)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the moment $T_{k-1}$ we are on a boundary of non-visited and visited points. Now what Lawler$^*$ says is that there are two possibilities (both having probability $1/2$):

- We step into the non-visited area. Then we have $T_{k} - T_{k-1} = 1$.
- We step back into the visited area. Then $$
  T_{k} - T_{k-1} = 1+ \text{time to reach the boundary again} \\+ \text{time to visit a new vertex from the boundary}.
  $$
  The first time is distributed as in gambler ruin problem with $N = k-2$ and $j=1$, hence $k-3$. The second has the same distribution as $T_k - T_{k-1}$.

Hence follows the required recursion.

However, it is possible to give a much easier argument. $T_{k} - T_{k-1}$ is like gambler's ruin problem with $N = k$ and $j=1$, therefore,
$$
r(k) = E(T_k - T_{k-1}) = k-1.
$$

---

$^*$ I hope it was rather one of Lawler's students, who wrote this solution for him.

Comment: Thanks for your input! The "much easier argument" just occurred to me as well. You explanation of the original argument does make sense though. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but in your solution, why is the r.v. $T_k-T_{k-1}$ like in gambler's ruin problem? Thank you!

Comment: @harlem, at each moment the set of visited vertices is an interval. When we hit a new vertex, we are at its endpoint, and we need to calculate the expected time to exit the interval. This is exactly gambler's ruin problem statement.