# Probability question: Expected number of trips for an alien to visit all $n$ planets in an orbit by only moving left or right

Tags: probability, expected-value

I came across problem which I cannot seem to solve when self studying probability. I was wondering if people can help me out.

> There are $n$ planets in an orbit. So, there are $n$ planets in a
> circle. An alien starts on one of the planets. With probability $p$ he
> can move to the right planet. With probability $1-p$ he can move to
> the left planet. What is the expected number of trips needed in order
> for the alien to visit all $n$ planets at least once.

Attempt:

Let $t$ be the number of trips or moves. We want to find $E[t|n]$.
The base cases are easy: $E[t|n=1]=1$,  $E[t|n=2]=2$.
$E[t|n=3]$ becomes more challenging and I can't seem to find something that generalizes.
I know this can also be modelled as a markov matrix, but unsure how to find the expected number of moves to visit all planets. Even assuming $p=\frac{1}{2}$ I cannot seem to find a solution or a good approach.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445154/step-in-computation-of-the-expected-cover-time-for-the-simple-random-walk-on-a-d) is a duplicate for the case $p=\frac 12$.  The same technique should be adaptable.

Comment: Why does gamblers ruin apply here? I was hoping for a more intuitive approach.

Comment: Gambler's ruin clearly applies, given the approach they take (which seems entirely natural).  At any stage prior to the end, you have some contiguous block of nodes you have visited and you want to know how long you expect it to take you to get out of that block.  That's equivalent to gambler's ruin.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first solve the question for case of $p=\frac{1}{2}$
Let $X=\textrm{# steps till you visit all the planets} = X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n$

where $X_i$ = # steps from $(i-1)$th new visit to $i$th new visit
Note $X_1 = 0, X_2=1$

Note that to calculate $E[X_i]$, once you visit your $(i-1)$th new planet, the next new planet is either 1 step(right/left) or $i-1$ steps(left/right) thus, if you lay them down flat on a straight line $E[X_i]$ boils down to calculate expected # of steps in a random walk before you reach $-1$ or $i-1$ and for $p=1/2$ it is equal to $i-1$

Hence $E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i] = 0+1+2+\ldots+n-1=n(n-1)/2$

For $p\neq1/2$, only change is in calculating $E[X_i]$, in a non symmetric random walk $S_n - n(2p-1)$ is a martingale, so if you use Optional Stopping time theorem, you get an exact expression for $E[X_i]$, but it is quite ugly so I'm leaving it, here is a link for your reference (3.3): [https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mabat/MARTINGALE_THEORY_2016/MT_SOL_03.pdf](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Emabat/MARTINGALE_THEORY_2016/MT_SOL_03.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, did you mean to write $X_1 = 1$? Can you please explain  "boils down to calculate expected # of steps in a random walk before you reach −1
 or i−1  and for p=1/2 it is equal to i−1" further?

Comment: $X_1=0$ your first visit which is the planet you're initially on,  imagine you've visited $i-1$ planets, so they must be contiguous or together on the circle and once you visit your $i-1$ th planet to visit the next planet is either 1 step (clockwise say) or $i-1$ steps counter clockwise, so if you mark the point you're currently on as 0, clockwise point -1, and counter clockwise points 1, ..., i-1, this boils down to calculating expected number of steps in a random walk until your reach -1 or i-1. This is a standard type of random walk question (expected # steps till you reach -b or a $= ab$)